# Android Camera does not show open gallery only works when restart phone

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to open gallery in android custom camera. However it shows and save sdcard when restart phone. What is the problem in my code?

```
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the question, are you asking why the Open Gallery Button shows only when you restart the phone or Why the photo shows up only after restart?

If it's the latter, Try  invoking the media scanner. Either before the Toast or after.

```
public void addPictureToGallery(String fileName) {
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: I am asking why open gallery button shows only restart phone. I tried like that. if (id == R.id.open_gallery) {
         Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,Uri.parse("content://media/internal/images/media"));
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);        Does not show anything

Comment: A button on your camera app shows up only when you restart the phone? Are you hiding the button anywhere? Does the button show up if you start the app afresh?

Comment: I used menu, when i press take photo menu on my app, it saved sdcart and then when i press open gallery menu on my app does not show picture.After restarting phone, it shows images

Comment: Call the addPictureToGallery